# Break apart this append message

Tags: jquery, html

This was created as simple jquery Store Cart feature. however, I am not as clean wiht getting the data to dynamically show to correct HTML5 elements (divs).

This append Code sucks, but works. anytime I modify it, breaks give a NaN value for quantity

```
        $('#left_bar .cart-info').append('<dt class="clearfix first_item last_item" id="each-'+thisID+'"><span class="quantity-formated" ><span class="shop quantity">1</span>x</span><div class="label">'+itemname+'</div><div class="shop price"> $<em>'+itemprice+'</em></div><span class="shop quantity">1</span><img src="remove.png" class="remove" /><br class="all" /></dt>');
```

I reall y want to just have the jquery vars go to HTML Div elements of choic i shopping cart.

Can anyone look at this and tell me how to achieve that.

ex: $('cart-product).find('quantity').html(iitemquanitity); something like this, wher eThe value can just be writte. The append is not working out.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing DOM manipulation the way you're describing, you should look into [micro-templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/).

Some popular libraries:

- http://underscorejs.org/#template
- http://mustache.github.io/
- http://handlebarsjs.com/

Here is a way to define a template for your HTML (such that the code is ignored by the browser onload, also using ERB style delimeters):

```
<script type='text/html' id='tmpl-item'>
    <dt class="clearfix first_item last_item" id="each-<%= thisID %>">
       <span class="quantity-formated">
           <span class="shop quantity"> <%= itemquantity %> </span> x
       </span>
       <div class="label"><%= itemname %></div>
       <div class="shop price"> $<em><%= itemprice %></em> </div>
       <span class="shop quantity"><%= itemquantity %></span>
       <img src="remove.png" class="remove">
       <br class="all" />
    </dt>
</script>
```

Here's how you'd render the template: grab that template and pass a context (some values) in to have them replaced..

```
var tmplHTML = document.getElementById('tmpl-item').innerHTML;

// rudimentary example 
// high level idea -> get the template HTML and replace variables
var html = tmplHTML.replace('<%= itemname %>', itemname);
html = html.replace('<%= itemprice %>',itemprice);
html = html.replace('<%= thisID %>',thisID);
html = html.replace('<%= itemquantity %>', itemquanity);
$('#left_bar .cart-info').append(html);

// with something like underscore, where an object is 
// evaluated as part of the template rendering process
// and your template is free form JS
var tmpl = _.template(tmplHTML);
var vals = { itemname: 'test', itemprice: '20', thisID: 'test', itemquanity: 1 };
$('#left_bar .cart-info').append(tmpl(vals));
```

Comment: This Method appears to be 100% javascript, I am writing it as jQuery.

   var tmplHTML = document.getElementById('tmpl-item').innerHTML;

I don't know if this works with jquery though.

Comment: Is there not  simpler method, that wold involve just writing to the HTML element.

Comment: I tried that method in my jquery script. It did not works as needed.

Comment: Only Price was printing, not any of the other fields.